# Spring beans config files not finding classes from dependencies declared in gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gradle

I'm trying to get the Eclipse STS plugin to validate my spring bean config files, however I'm getting a class not found exception for every class that is outside of the current project (but is still in a dependent project obviously), There's an option to "Update Maven Dependencies" in the Spring Tools menu but that fails due to it not being a Maven project.

Is there a way to tell the plugin to look at the gradle dependencies ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice, ended up moving to Kepler instead of Juno which seemed to solve the issue anyway, so most likely was something to do with my plugins not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
```

Then try

```
gradle eclipseClean
gradle eclipse
```

on your project directory.  It should erase any eclipse configuration you have on your project and regenerate everything (.classpath, war generation settings) in order to match your gradle dependencies.  Beware that this is quite intrusive, as it wipes out your eclipse manual configuration (it is actually a gradle coup d'état to your eclipse configuration :P)

Comment: Alternatively, install the STS Gradle plugin.